# How can I edit a cell in Google Sheets which is linked to a file name in Google Drive?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-drive

I currently have a Google Spreadsheet with two columns - the file ID of a set of files, the file name. I want to write a Google Apps Script where when I change the file name within the spreadsheet, it renames the file associated with it (fileID) to the new name and vice versa.

With changing it on the spreadsheet, should I use simple/installable onEdit or onChange, and how might I implement this in code. I don't know how to do this vice versa as well.

Here's what I have so far, but the trigger has failed quite a few times. It's throwing the exception:

```
Exception: The parameters () don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange.
at onEdit(edit:3:24)
```

and

```
Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
```

---

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxx").getSheetByName("New");
  var range = e.source.getRange();
  range.setComment("Last modified: " + (new Date())+' by '+Session.getActiveUser());
  Logger.log(range.getRow() + " " + range.getColumn());

  var newName = range.getValue();
  var fileID = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1).getValue();
  if (range.getColumn == 3) { // just some data validation to make sure the edited cell is in column 3 
    Logger.log(range.getValue());
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);
    file.setName(newName);
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] You should use a installable trigger, it could be edit or change trigger. If you need further help, please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. May I respectfully suggest that you read up and research the subject of [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events?hl=en). For example, ` var range = e.source.getRange();` is failing because 1) [source]() returns "A Spreadsheet object" - so you would still need to add methods to get  the (Active??) sheet, and 2) `getRange()` requires [parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#getrangerow,-column) . OTOH, `e.range` returns "A Range object,"